# how join two dataframe in pyspark with a special condition?

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 dataframes I wanna join them with respect of 3 column. The first  column have an exact match the second column has an exact match if the value of `df1` is not `NA`.  but third column is not an exact match it is inclusion:

join rows of `df1` with `df2` if `col1` in `df1` and `col1` in `df2` have the same values and elements of `col3` in `df1` is included in elements of `col3` in `df2` and if `col1` in `df1` is not `NA` and have the same value in `col2` in df2 (if it is `NA` but other 2 conditions are valid then match them ).

Example

df1:

```
col1     col2            col3
us        NA             amazon 
ca        Vancouver      Facebook
IN        Ottawa         IBM
```

df2:

```
col1     col2              col3
ca        Vancouver      /n Facebook us
IN        Boston         IBM
us        new york       amazon IN
```

output:

```
ca        Vancouver      Facebook
us        new york       amazon
```

Comment: how did `ca - Vancouver - Facebook` match?

Comment: Sorry I editted the question, thanks

Comment: can you please elaborate/simplify the join conditions stated? based on what's written, your output should have 0 records as "*col1 in df1 is not NA and have the same value in col2 in df2*" is always false

Comment: `col1` in The first row in `df1` has the same value as third row in `df2' also `amazon` in the third column of `df1` is included in `amazon IN` in the third column of `df2`. So even if the secon column of `df1` is `NA` but they match

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('us',None,'amazon')
    ,('ca','Vancouver','Facebook')
    ,('IN','Ottawa','IBM')
    ],
    ['col1','col2','col3']
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('ca','Vancouver','/n Facebook us')
    ,('IN','Boston','IBM')
    ,('us','new york','amazon IN')
    ],
    ['col1','col2','col3']
)

df1.show()
df2.show()

# +----+---------+--------+
# |col1|     col2|    col3|
# +----+---------+--------+
# |  us|     null|  amazon|
# |  ca|Vancouver|Facebook|
# |  IN|   Ottawa|     IBM|
# +----+---------+--------+

# +----+---------+--------------+
# |col1|     col2|          col3|
# +----+---------+--------------+
# |  ca|Vancouver|/n Facebook us|
# |  IN|   Boston|           IBM|
# |  us| new york|     amazon IN|
# +----+---------+--------------+

df1\
    .join(df2, 'col1')\
    .withColumn('flag', F.when(df1.col2.isNull() & df2.col3.contains(df1.col3) , 1).
                              when(df1.col2 == df2.col2, 1).otherwise(0))\
    .filter(F.col('flag') == 1)\
    .select(df1.col1, df2.col2, df1.col3)\
    .show()

# +----+---------+--------+
# |col1|     col2|    col3|
# +----+---------+--------+
# |  ca|Vancouver|Facebook|
# |  us| new york|  amazon|
# +----+---------+--------+
```